# Doctrine - querybuider setParameters with array (nested/multiples values)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Doctrine in my PHP application (but not using Symfony). I try to make a dynamic query with only one addWhere/orWhere.

Here is my code:

```
$alias = 'a';
$key = 'id';
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder($alias);
$qb->select($alias);
$qb->andWhere($alias . ' = ' . $key);

// Key is "id" and value is a dynamic array "[1, 2, 3, 6...]"
$qb->setParameter($key, $value);
```

If value is only "1" I got this DQL :

```
SELECT a FROM contact a WHERE a = :id
```

And it works. But with value as an array, I want to do this query without multiple "andOr" because my array is dynamic. Is there a method to automatically add (addWhere or orWhere) to get that automatically using my array:

```
SELECT a FROM contact a WHERE a = :id OR a:= id OR a:= id
```

I know I can do a for loop myself but I want to know if there is already an existing method in doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `IN` instruction.

```
$alias = 'a';
$key = 'id';
$values = [1, 2, 3];
$qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder($alias);
$qb->select($alias);
$qb->where(\sprintf("%s.%s IN (:values)", $alias, $key));

$qb->setParameter('values', $values);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Works great!